# Animation and Collision detection using Cocos2D/Box2d - iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am developing an iphone game using cocos2d and box2d. I use cococ2d to animate a sprite (using series of png). 
In box2D I make a body and

- Set its shape to polygon using setAsBox().
- And set its user data to the sprite that I had created in cocos2D.

Problem: The collision seems very unrealistic as the animated sprite is concave in shape and the box that I had made in box2D doesnt in any way meet the dimensions of the animated sprite.

I have tried vertex helper to make the b2Body a particular shape but after much efforts found out that concave shaped cannot be made using vertices.

Any help on this problem please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using multiply shapes per one body for better approximation

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a ton of time and check these out.  You will be amazed how easy it is to get really cool physics working.

http://www.spritehelper.org/

http://www.physicseditor.de/features/